# How to use Autolayout Programmatically to give vertical space between views?

Tags: iphone, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

In my app i have to layout two views vertically according to each and want to make sure they look similar in iPhone 4&5.
Here's the code :

```
nextShowView = [[WestwoodNextShowView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(-5, 322, 290, 70)];
    nextShowView.staticLabel.text = @"Next Show";
    nextShowView.date.text = @"10/25";
    nextShowView.address.text = @"Green Dot Tavern";
    nextShowView.cityState.text = @"Detroit, MI";
    [_aboutScroll addSubview:nextShowView];

    playerView = [[WestwoodMusicPlayerView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 407, 320, 50)];
        [_aboutScroll addSubview:playerView];

    NSDictionary * viewsDict = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(nextShowView, playerView);
    NSArray * constraints = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:[nextShowView]-15-[playerView]-20-|" options:NSLayoutFormatAlignAllLeft metrics:nil views:viewsDict];
    [_aboutScroll addConstraints:constraints];
```

What i tried to do is to give 15 point space between nextShowView and playerView and 20 point space from playerView bottom to the view bottom edge.

Please help !!!!

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Autolayout only works if you provide *all* the constraints that every view needs to specify it completely. You must give not only the vertical separation between `nextShowView` and `playerView`, not only the vertical separation between `playerView` and the superview, but also their heights, and also their horizontal positions and widths.

If your views do not appear where you expect them, you probably have given insufficient constraints. Pause in the debugger and say `po [[UIWindow keyWindow] _autolayoutTrace]` at the console command line to confirm whether you have ambiguous layout.